# What is an 'Oriented' Band-pass Filter?

Tags: image-processing, filter-design, bandpass

In [this research paper](http://jivp.eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/articles/10.1155/2010/680429), Section 4.1 talks about a filter called "Oriented Band-pass Filter".

**What does it actually mean by *'Orientation'*?**

Also, the article gives a function,

$$H(u, v) = \frac{1}{1 + 0.414(\sqrt{\frac{u^*}{D_h} + \frac{v^*}{D_v} })^{2n}}$$

Can you please explain this function in layman's terms?

What are $u$, $v$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that by orientation they mean rotation of coordinates.
$u,v$ are the horizontal and vertical frequencies while $u^*,v^*$ are the rotated frequencies. 
If i understand correctly, they are looking for a line in an image with unknown rotation (aka slope) so they create of filter-bank of *oriented* filter, each with a different rotation.